# tf.compat.v1 not recognizing the module contrib

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I run with TensorFlow 2 a python code initially developed with TensorFlow 1 :

For a first quick test I transformed the code using `tf.compat.v1`

```
W = tf.compat.v1.get_variable(
    "W",
    shape=[num_filters_total, num_classes],
    initializer=tf.compat.v1.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
```

Strangely it shows `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v1' has no attribute 'contrib'`

What is wrong here?

Comment: You cannot use `contrib` in Tensorflow 2, it has been removed completely. You will need to downgrade TF or replace any calls to `contrib`.

Comment: @xdurch0 yes but with compat it should bring compatibility, no?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The module has been removed completely, even from `compat.v1`. But as you seem to have found, many functionalities in there are obsolete anyway. Others have been moved into core or into packages such as `tensorflow-probability`.

Answer (score 1):

```
tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal
```

Is the equivalent in TF 2 of the defunct Xavier Initializer. Xavier Glorot.